# VSTO localization and setting CurrentUICulture on the main thread

Tags: localization, ms-office, vsto

I have VSTO Application level add-ins that need to show localized resources within the ribbon. I know best practices are to utilize the CurrentUICulture on the current thread for localiztion, but it seems that the main thread I have access to within my add-ins is shared among all other VSTO add-ins. I do not want to be a bad citizen and set this property on a shared main thread, and alternatively I am afraid that if I were to rely on this setting it could be changed without my knowledge. Is there any suitable workaround within VSTO or is the best practice to basically keep some static marker with the locale I need to use so I do not trounce on either Office OR other VSTO add-ins?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what Office application you are talking about. Take a look at the [How to: Localize Excel Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178762(v=VS.100).aspx#sectionToggle3) article in MSDN which describes to localize Office add-ins.

Comment: I have tested within Word and have two distinct VSTO application level addins, but this applies to Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook. I am using the ability for a user to choose their own locale for my addin and generated resources for all of my strings to do lookup based on locale. It feels completely wrong to set the CurrentUICulture on the main thread if it's shared between the addins (which it appears to be based on my initial testing). I have looked through the normal MSDN/dev.office.com searches and cannot get any insight as to if we should be setting the property on the main thread.

Comment: FWIW, 6 years later, I am seeing the same issue as in your original post (Excel VSTO add-ins).  Did you ever find a reasonable answer for how to behave like a good citizen and not have an impact on other add-ins?